# How can I write the eyes emoji in Skype?

Tags: skype-for-web

How can I write the eyes emoji in Skype?

I mean this emoji:

[image]

While I know that if I write the `(eyespeechbubble)` I will get this emoji:

[image]

So, I would hope for there being a code something like `(eye)` or `(eyes)`, but I was not able to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(eyespeechbubble)` is not included on [What is the full list of emoticons?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12330/what-is-the-full-list-of-emoticons), so it's very likely that there isn't a another shortcut for

Comment: I am confused. How someone with so much reputation as you can not know how to make logical conclusions. You say that `(eyespeechbubble) is not included ...` in some list of emoticons, but it is still possible to use the typing to get the emoji. So, it is naturally to expect that the same could be for the two eyes emoji. While you are saying a completely opposite thing.

Comment: Any explanation of your logical conclusion?